# Преобразование ДНК в РНК в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> Create a function which translates a given DNA string into RNA.

Подскажите как сделать это?

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-algorithm-dna-to-rna-conversion-cceb6abc1336 первый же результат в поиске.

Comment: Переведите вопрос полностью на русский язык

Comment: по тому как задан вопрос ответ может быть `const dna = "DNA; let rna = dna; rna[0] = 'R'"` :)

Comment: Спасибо))))))))

Comment: @Zhihar таки не сработает, строки неизменяемые xD

Answer (score 1):

Нашел похожую задачу на [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5556282156230d0e5e000089)

> Deoxyribonucleic acid, DNA is the primary information storage molecule in biological systems. It is composed of four nucleic acid bases Guanine ('G'), Cytosine ('C'), Adenine ('A'), and Thymine ('T').

> Ribonucleic acid, RNA, is the primary messenger molecule in cells. RNA differs slightly from DNA its chemical structure and contains no Thymine. In RNA Thymine is replaced by another nucleic acid Uracil ('U').

Поэтому все, что нам требуется - это заменить тимин `T` на урацил `U`.

```js
const dna = [
  'TTTT',
  'GCAT',
  'GATTCCACCGACTTCCCAAGTACCGGAAGCGCGACCAACTCGCACAGC'
];

console.log(dna.map(e => e.replace(/T/g, 'U')));
```